# android ExpandableListView - NullPointerException

Tags: android, expandablelistview

> Blockquote

I'm using ExpandableListView in android

this is the code of getChildView in the adapter class:

```
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         ViewHolder holder; 
        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childrow, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(); 

            holder.tv = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                            // I added this line of code
                holder.stop = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button3);

            holder.position = groupPosition;
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            holder.stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

               ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
               holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

                    int position = 0;

                        position = holder.position; ************* here

                    System.out.println("coolapse tag " + position);

                    expList.collapseGroup(position);


                }
            });

        } else {
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

It gives NullPointerException in the line marked by ******
what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `holder.stop`? `holder.stop` is NOT the view where you set the tag, so when you try to do `v.getTag()`, you get a null in `holder` (incidentally, I did not see `holder.stop` being initialized). Not sure exactly what you're going for, but a way to fix it would be to set the holder on the `stop` view as well:

```
convertView.setTag(holder);
holder.stop.setTag(holder);
holder.stop.setOnClickListener(....
```

Comment: it is a class

 static class ViewHolder{
  
  Button stop;
  TextView tv;
  int position;
 }

Comment: You can't use a static class, you need one holder instance per view.

Comment: I changed it to public class // nothing has changed

Comment: Wait, I got confused, that doesn't matter. Did you try setting the holder in the `stop` Button as well?

Comment: Did setting the tag on the stop button? `holder.stop.setTag(holder);` . Alternatively, you can just set the position as the button's tag, no need for the holder.

Comment: but I need to do some stuff with the textView and another elements I didn't mentioned in the code

Comment: Oh ok, then try and set the holder in the button!